# Convert excel with varying col/rowspans to HTML table in Codeigniter 4 using phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, html-table, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

[image]

As you can see from the image that there multiple rows and columns that are merged in here. I need help to convert these merged cells to be shown in a HTML table as it is using php loops.

I have tried multiple libraries but was not able to succeed. Because the merged rows and columns can be anywhere into the excel file and I want it to be as it is.